# count number of occurences of substring and keep highest score

Tags: linux, sed, scripting, sort, uniq

I have a list of string like:

```
StringA  45
StrinB  98 
StringA  35
StringA  83
StrinB  78
StringC  65
StrinB  98
```

and I want to filter out duplicates, print the number of occurences (of the substring that can be of different length but will be delimited by ^(beginning of string) on one side, \tab on the other) plus print only the highest number found associated with the string i.e. I want the output to be something like (the string, number of occurrences & score can also appear in a different order):

```
3 83 StringA
3 98 StrinB
1 65 StringC
```

I understand that I can use a combination of `sort` and `uniq` to sort the same occurrences and remove duplicates but that does not account different "scores". I'm wondering how I can sort while ignoring the scores and then filter out duplicates while keeping track of the highest score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datamash -sg 1 count 1 max 2 < input.txt | awk '{print $2, $3, $1}'
```

**Explanation**

1. `datamash -sg 1 count 1 max 2 < input.txt`

   - `-s` - sort  the  input  before  grouping; this removes the need to manually pipe the input through `sort`.
   - `-g 1` - group by first column.
   - `count 1` - count number of elements in the group.
   - `max 2` - print the maximum second column's value for each group.
2. `awk '{print $2, $3, $1}'` - rearrangement of fields.

**Output**

```
3 98 StrinB
3 83 StringA
1 65 StringC
```

Comment: very cool! I'll have to pickup on using `datamash`, looks like an amazing tool! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

that could be done by `awk` itself:

```
awk '{ max[$1]=( max[$1]>$2?max[$1]:$2 ); seen[$1]++ } 
    END{ for (x in seen) print seen[x], max[x], x }' infile
3 98 StrinB
3 83 StringA
1 65 StringC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

`awk '{print $2" "$1}' file.txt | sort -k2 -rk1 | uniq -f1 -c | awk '{print $3" "$1" "$2}'`

- `-k2` will sort the second field.
- `-rk1` will reverse sort the first field.
- `-f1` will ignore the **up to** first field to check unique

Comment: Yes, While it works on the example data I provided, it doesn't seem to work the same way on my "real" data - I have to figure out what wrong....

Comment: I don't understand, `sort -k1,1 file` returns me this: txt.do/dzgcr but it doesn't get processed by `uniq` as it is expected, only the first line gets processed and it seems to count every line. Can you further assist me? Thanks!

Comment: @cerr a small misQ , `-f` will ignore up to number fields. Let me know if my updated answer works with your real data.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small perl script if that option works for you to achieve what you want

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
my (%max,%count);
open(my $fh,'<',"<INPUT FILE>");  #open input file for reading
while(my $line = <$fh>){. 
        my ($string,$score) = split(' ',$line);
        $count{$string}++;       
        if(defined $max{$string}){
                if($score > $max{$string}){
                        $max{$string} = $score;
                }
        }
        else{
                $max{$string} = $score;
        }
}
for my $string ( keys%max){
        print "$count{$string} $max{$string} $string\n";
}
```

`%count` hash will contain the number of occurrences of each string

> ```
> >    $VAR1 = {
> >               'StrinB' => 3,
> >               'StringC' => 1,
> >               'StringA' => 3
> >             };
> ```

`%max` will contain maximum score for each string

> ```
>    $VAR1 = {
>                'StrinB' => 98,
>                'StringC' => '65',
>                'StringA' => 83
>              };
> ```